# Meaning of Objective and Risk in DLIB HOG-SVM detector

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, support-vector-machine

I am using dlib simple object detector for training a HOG-SVM object detector. Everything is working fine when I test manually. However, I can't find any resources that tell me what is the meaning of some of the metrices that are shown while training. These are:

1. Objective - What is the objective function?
2. Objective Gap - Is it the difference between the objective function of the current and previous iteration?
3. Risk - No idea what this is.
4. Risk Gap - Evidently no idea what this is.

I can intuitively understand that the lower the above metrices the better the model is. However I have no formal way to define the above or explain what the metrices are.

Can someone please explain the metrices in the list? Some good resource to get a bit more enlightenment will also be good.